# Check each List item if Null

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sharepoint

I am quite poor at writing code, hence the question. Below I am adding items into a SharePoint List from a DB while checking if any of the fields contains DBNulls. Rather than having to perform the check for each column like I am below, can someone help me to put it in a loop if possible? I would be forever grateful

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = "dsn=abc;uid=xyz;pwd=yuo;DataSource=aaa";
    connection.ConnectionTimeout = 100;
    connection.Open();

    OdbcCommand command_donor = new OdbcCommand("Select * From vw_SP_aaa_bbb", connection);

    try
    {
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = command_donor.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                var obj0 = reader.GetValue(48);
                var obj1 = reader.GetValue(0);
                var obj2 = reader.GetValue(33);
                var obj3 = reader.GetValue(47);
                var obj4 = reader.GetValue(42);
                var obj5 = reader.GetValue(42);


                ListItem oListItem_aaa = oList_aaa .AddItem(itemCreateInfo);


                if (obj0 == null || obj0.Equals(DBNull.Value))
                { oListItem_aaa["Title"] = ""; }
                else
                { oListItem_aaa["Title"] = reader.GetString(48).ToString(); }

                if (obj1 == null || obj1.Equals(DBNull.Value))
                { oListItem_aaa["aaa_x0020_ID"] = ""; }
                else
                { oListItem_aaa["aaa_x0020_ID"] = reader.GetString(0).ToString(); }

                if (obj2 == null || obj2.Equals(DBNull.Value))
                { oListItem_aaa["Excluded_x0020_By"] = ""; }
                else
                { oListItem_aaa["Excluded_x0020_By"] = reader.GetString(33).ToString(); }

                if (obj3 == null || obj3.Equals(DBNull.Value))
                { oListItem_aaa["Excluded_x0020_On"] = ""; }
                else
                { oListItem_aaa["Excluded_x0020_On"] = reader.GetDateTime(47).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }

                if (obj4 == null || obj4.Equals(DBNull.Value))
                { oListItem_aaa["Reason"] = ""; }
                else
                { oListItem_aaa["Reason"] = reader.GetString(42).Substring(50, reader.GetString(42).ToString().Length-50); }

                if (obj5 == null || obj5.Equals(DBNull.Value))
                { oListItem_aaa["Publish"] = ""; }
                else
                { oListItem_aaa["Publish"] = reader.GetString(42).Substring(50, reader.GetString(42).ToString().Length - 50); }

                oListItem_aaa.Update();

                context.ExecuteQuery();

            }

        }

    }

    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Error is:" + exception);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of a loop I'd suggest writing a method that handles the duplicated logic.  Or alternatively you could change your query to coalesce the null values.

Comment: I would also recommend add a where clause to the Select statement to filter out records and or data that you know would return Null values.. also for readability personally I would not use the `GetString` method ..what if the columns order changes..? you should be accessing the `reader["FieldName"].ToString()` that way makes for easier reading

Comment: juharr: Thanks for the comment. Could you please show me an example that I could follow? I know I am asking too much but, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Short IIF like

```
oListItem_aaa["Excluded_x0020_By"] = (obj1 == null || obj1.Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : reader.GetString(0).ToString();
```

or

```
var obj0 = (reader.GetValue(48) != DBNull.Value && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(48)))) ? reader.GetValue(48) : "");
```

in one line. Then you dont need to use the if then else's... described also in MSDN at [Operator ?: (C#-Referenz)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I used it and it works. Brilliant, thank you very much.